# Reference for explicit formula used by Ramanujan

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta-function

In his work on highly composite numbers [http://math.univ-lyon1.fr/~nicolas/ramanujanNR.pdf](http://math.univ-lyon1.fr/%7Enicolas/ramanujanNR.pdf) , Ramanujan used a version of an explicit formula (equation (329) on page 133) relating primes and zeros of the $\zeta$ function. Can anybody please give me a reference for this formula?

Comment: Since this is mostly just digging up literature I wonder if in a few years time tools like gpt-4 can assist with a request like this.

Comment: The formula in question is $$x-\theta(x)=\sqrt x+x^{1/3}+\sum{x^{\rho}\over\rho}-\sum{x^{\rho/2}\over\rho}+O(x^{1/5})$$

Comment: Yes, this is the formula that I'd like a reference for

Comment: do you mean a reference to where it is *proved* in the literature?

Comment: Ideally I would like a reference where the formula is proved, but I would also be happy with any other reference that discusses/mentions the formula.

Comment: In the very same paper you mentioned a reference is in the notes.